# Is there a "follow-mode" when moving through a magit-log (or similar buffers)?

Tags: magit

I have some recollection that there was something like a "follow-mode" for some `magit` buffers (e.g., `magit-log`). The idea was that I could pull up a log (e.g., with `C-x g l l`), put point on the first line, display the associated commit with `SPC`, and then when I moved up/down (with `C-n` or `C-p`), the commit displayed in the `magit-revision` buffer would automatically (asynchronously?) update to correspond to whatever was at point, but perhaps I had to use a different command (`C-u SPC`?) to show thing at point in a way that would then enable "following").

This was (or would be) really useful if I was e.g., trying to quickly review a series of commits from a collaborator. Of course I can just mash `SPC` every time I move point, but in the same way that I find `helm`'s `follow-mode` really helpful when I'm aggressively searching, I think it'd be really nice in `magit`, too.

I don't know if this feature still exists (or if it ever existed, maybe it was all a dream) but I've scoured the `magit` manual, functions, and variables for terms like `follow`, `jump`, `move`, `auto`, etc, and I can't track anything down.

Does this kind of functionality exist, and if not did it ever? It seems like the sort of thing that perhaps would get axed for performance reasons, but that if so maybe there's a toggle somewhere so that I could re-enable it as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, writing a SE question often forces me to do more homework and solve my own problem. The solution is to move through the log with `n` and `p` rather than `C-n` and `C-p`

`C-n` and `C-p` call the usual line movement commands, but `n` and `p` (or for me in `spacemacs`, it's `]` and `[`) call `magit-section-forward-sibling` and `magit-section-backward-sibling` respectively. These commands do end up invoking `magit-section-movement-hook` which (by default) includes things like `magit-log-maybe-update-revision-buffer` which has the behavior I was looking for.

Hooray!